# How to force a 5GHz wifi connection?

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, broadcom

It seems that whenever I start up my computer, it will be using a 5GHz connection for around 5 minutes, but any time after that it will switch to using 2.4GHz. All other devices are capable of staying on a 5Ghz connection, but not my PC. Is there any way to force a 5GHz connection? Everywhere I've checked online suggests changing an option in the network adapter properties called "Preferred Band," but that option doesn't appear for me. The closest equivalent I have is called "Roaming Decision," which I have set to "Optimize Bandwidth." When I first enabled this, I connected instantly to 5GHz, but shortly after it switched back to 2.4Ghz and stayed there. This also seems to happen after booting up my computer. Additionally, I've tried updating the drivers of the network adapter, but device manager says they're all up to date. I looked on the Broadcom website to see if there were any newer drivers, but it's hellish to navigate, and I'm not sure that my network card is even listed as a product.

My network adapter is a Broadcom 802.11ac. Both the 2.4GHz and 5GHz connections are part of one network. My PC is running Windows 10. Device manager says the drivers are up to date. The router I'm connected to is located in the hallway just outside the room my PC is in. Thank you for any help.

Comment: **Why** does the PC switch to 2.4 GHz? Is it farther from the router? Low frequencies penetrate walls better than high, so perhaps the signal is weak. WiFiInfoVoiew https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wifi_information_view.html , will show signal strength, as well as providing a shortcut to the 5 GHz service.

Comment: Why do you want to force 5GHz? A higher frequency does not result in faster speeds automatically, it may actually slow things down.